# Speed issue with huge C array using 64bit Visual C

Tags: c, performance, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I need to read a massive amount of data into a buffer (about 20gig).   I have 192gb of very fast DDram available, so no issue with memory size.  However, I am finding that the following code runs slower and slower the further it gets into the buffer.  The Visual C profiler tells me that 68% of the 12 minute execution time is in the 2 statements inside the loop in myFunc().  I am running win7, 64bit on a very fast dell with 2 cpu's, 6 physical cores each (24 logical cores), and all 24 cores are completely maxed out while running this.

```
#define TREAM_COUNT 9000
#define ARRAY_SIZE ONE_BILLION

#define offSet(a,b,c,d) ( ((size_t)  ARRAY_SIZE * (a)) + ((size_t) TREAM_COUNT * 800 * (b)) + ((size_t) 800 * (c)) + (d) )

void myFunc(int dogex, int ptxIndex, int xtreamIndex, int carIndex)
{
     short *ptx  =  (short *) calloc(ARRAY_SIZE * 20, sizeof(short));

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int bIndex = 0; bIndex < 800; ++bIndex)
          doWork(dogex, ptxIndex, carIndex);
}

 void doWork(int dogex, int ptxIndex, int carIndex)
{

    for (int treamIndex = 0; treamIndex < ONE_BILLION; ++treamIndex)
    {
         short ptxValue     =  ptx[ offSet(dogex, ptxIndex,   treamIndex, carIndex) ];
         short lastPtxValue =  ptx[ offSet(dogex, ptxIndex-1, treamIndex, carIndex) ];

         // ....
    }

}
```

Comment: You can optimize the code by getting rid of the multiplications (either by shifting or addition). But still that might not solve your problem of the loop getting slower.

Comment: Why are you assigning ptxValue and lastPtxValue in the loop? Both assignments appear to be independent of looping.

Comment: My apologies...in trying to simplify the code, I got it wrong (the edited version is above).  Inside the 'for' loop there is a changing value, which is why the calcs need to be done over and over again.

Comment: Here is a useful exercise: Split each assignment into separate statements: (a) calculation of offset into a temp variable (b) reading ptx using the offset. Which one is slow? The math or the memory access.

Comment: Also: try to reproduce your problem with an http://sscce.org/ version of your code, instead of the whole thing.

Comment: "all 24 cores are completely maxed out" - how is this possible? this looks like a single-threaded code...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - I expect that OP has oversimplified code when sharing with us :) Happened once already [which led to a few 'wrong' answers which we posted/deleted]

Comment: I agree with Karoly. If this code maxes out all cores, something else must be happening in your app.

Comment: how does `ptx` can be accessed on `doWork()` function ? isn't it declared in `myFunc`?

Comment: if you call something 800 billion times, it could get slower.

Comment: @user994179: can you describe what happens in the inner loop? also how do you measure: "it gets slower and slower"?

Comment: @user994179 - did you try what I asked you to do in my earlier comment? If yes, what do you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code allocated 20 blocks of one billion short ints.  On a 64-bit Windows box, a short int is 2 bytes.  So the allocation is ~40 gigabytes.

You say there are 24 cores and they're all maxed out.  The code as it is doesn't appear to show any parallelism.  The way in which the code is parallelised could have a profound effect upon performance.  You may need to provide more information.

--

Your basic problem, I suspect, revolves around cache behaviour and memory access limits.

First, with two physical CPUs of six cores each, you will utterly saturate your memory bus.  Probably you have a NUMA architecture anyway, but there's no control in the code about where your calloc() allocates (e.g. you could have a lot of code stored in memory which requires multiple hops to reach).

Hyperthreading is turned on.  This effectively halves cache sizes.  Given the code is memory bus bound, rather than compute bound, hyperthreading is harmful.  (Having said that, if computation is constantly outside of cache bounds anyway, this won't change much).

It's not clear (since some/much?) code is removed, how the array is being accessed and the access pattern and optimimzation of that pattern to honour cache optimization is the key to performance.

What I see in how offset() is caculated is that the code is constantly requiring the generation of new virtual to physical address lookups - each of which requires something like four or five memory accesses.  This is kiling performance, by itself.

My basic advice would be break the array up into level 2 cache-sized blocks, give one block to each CPU and let it process that block.  You can do that in parallel.  Actually, you might be able to use hyperthreading to pre-load the cache, but that's a more advanced technique.

Comment: Did you notice `#pragma omp parallel for`?

Comment: userxxxx added it after this answer was posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you know where I could read more about these things (eg, memory bus limitation, L2 and L3 cache sizing in relation to memory alloc, etc)?  Thanks.

Comment: The white paper, by Ullrich Drepper, "What Every Programmer Should Know About Computer Memory".  Google search, it's all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

This optimization will get rid of the slow multiplications:

```
    ...
    int idx1 = offSet(dogex, ptxIndex,   0, carIndex);
    int idx2 = offSet(dogex, ptxIndex-1,   0, carIndex);

    for (int treamIndex = 0; treamIndex < ONE_BILLION; ++treamIndex)
    {             
         short ptxValue     =  ptx[ idx1 ];
         short lastPtxValue =  ptx[ idx2 ];
         idx1+=800;
         idx2+=800;             ...
```

Comment: +1. Although I get the feeling it's not the MULs that slow it down, but the LOADs from memory.

Comment: yes it also doesn't explain why the code would get slower over time, but it's an improvement :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to access array in more linear fashion if possible. This probably causes excessive amount of cache misses.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem of this code is its memory access pattern. The fact that each thread accesses memory in large (2*800 bytes) increments has 2 negative consequences:

1. At the start all threads access the same piece of memory, which is preloaded into L2/L3 cache and is efficiently used by every thread. Later on, threads proceed with slightly different speed and access different pieces of memory, which results in cache trashing (one thread loads data to cache and evicts data from there, which was not yet read by other threads, needing it). As a result, same piece of memory is read to the cache several times (in the worst case, 12 times, by the number of threads in one CPU). Since memory bus is relatively slow, this slows down the whole program.
2. L1 cache is also used not very efficiently: only small part of the data in each cache line is used by CPU cores.

The solution is to allow each thread to access memory sequentially (like exchanging `c` and `d` arguments of the `offSet(a,b,c,d)` macro).